# Write grid to text file in html format

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I have a data grid. I want to submit this data to the server and store it in a text file.

Here's the code I have so far:

```
var tbl = $('table#grid tbody tr').map(function (idx, el) {
               var td = $(el).find('td');
               var obj = { id: idx + 1 };

               for (var i = 0; i < tblhdr.length; i++) {
                   obj[tblhdr[i]] = td.eq(i).text();
               }
               return obj;
           }).get();
           tbl = JSON.stringify(tbl);
           var request = $.ajax({
               url: "../reports/S?tbl=" + tbl,//action method url which defined in controller
               type: 'POST',
               cache: false,
               data: JSON.stringify(tbl),
               dataType: 'text',
               contentType: 'application/text'
           });

 [HttpPost,ValidateInput(false)]
        public ActionResult reports(string tbl)
        {
            string table = tbl;
            StreamWriter file2 = new StreamWriter(@"D:\Demo.txt", true);
            file2.WriteLine(tbl);
            file2.Flush();
            file2.Close();

        }
```

I need the data in HTML form.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I'm sorry, but it's completely unclear to me what you're asking. Perhaps you could try phrasing it differently? Thanks.

Comment: i wanna send my data to controller in any form json/xml/html and then i want to write it to text document in html format as it is my report to send to client please give positiv reply

Comment: I've edited your question to make it clearer.